# Discord BOT ERROR in bot.js (SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token)

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, logging, discord

I am programming a Discord bot, i installed the files that i required, but when i put the command node bot.js on the command prompt, there a error.
This is my bot.js file

```
var Discord = require(‘discord.io’);
var logger = require(‘winston’);
var auth = require(‘./auth.json’);
// Configure logger settings
logger.remove(logger.transports.Console);
logger.add(new logger.transports.Console, {
colorize: true
});
logger.level = ‘debug’;
// Initialize Discord Bot
var bot = new Discord.Client({
token: auth.token,
autorun: true
});
bot.on(‘ready’, function (evt) {
logger.info(‘Connected’);
logger.info(‘Logged in as: ‘);
logger.info(bot.username + ‘ – (‘ + bot.id + ‘)’);
});
bot.on(‘message’, function (user, userID, channelID, message, evt) {
// Nuestro bot necesita saber si ejecutará un
// Escuchará los mensajes que empiecen con ‘¡’
if (message.substring(0, 1) == ‘h’) {
var args = message.substring(1).split(‘ ‘);
var cmd = args[0];
args = args.splice(1);
switch(cmd) {
// !ping
case ‘ping’:
bot.sendMessage({
to: channelID,
message: ‘“Que onda bro, me tiraste vino en la camisa por casualidad? jaja que elocuente’
});
break;
// Agrega cualquier comando si lo deseas
}
}
});
```

And the error is this:

```
C:\Users\patri.M2K606\Desktop\BOTS DISCORD\OCHOA (Musica)>node bot.js
C:\Users\patri.M2K606\Desktop\BOTS DISCORD\OCHOA (Musica)\bot.js:1
var Discord = require(‘discord.io’);


SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
[90m    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1047:16)[39m
[90m    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1097:27)[39m
[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1153:10)[39m
[90m    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:977:32)[39m
[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:877:14)[39m
[90m    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12)[39m
[90m    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:18:47[39m
```

Help me, i am new so i can not find the syntax error. I've been trying for two hours and it throws the same error.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the code other than having wrong quotes. Try using this code:

```
var Discord = require('discord.io');
var logger = require('winston');
var auth = require('./auth.json');

// Configure logger settings
logger.remove(logger.transports.Console);
logger.add(new logger.transports.Console, {
colorize: true
});
logger.level = 'debug';

// Initialize Discord Bot
var bot = new Discord.Client({
token: auth.token,
autorun: true
});

bot.on('ready', function (evt) {
logger.info('Connected');
logger.info('Logged in as: ');
logger.info(bot.username + ' – (' + bot.id + ')');
});

bot.on('message', function (user, userID, channelID, message, evt) {
// Nuestro bot necesita saber si ejecutará un
// Escuchará los mensajes que empiecen con ‘¡’
if (message.substring(0, 1) == 'h') {
var args = message.substring(1).split(' ');
var cmd = args[0];
args = args.splice(1);

switch(cmd) {
// !ping
case 'ping':
bot.sendMessage({
to: channelID,
message: '"Que onda bro, me tiraste vino en la camisa por casualidad? jaja que elocuente'"
});
break;
// Agrega cualquier comando si lo deseas
}
}
});
```